# SQL Database with duplicate

Tags: sql, sqlite

Say I have multiset in my table and  with the below I will get the duplicates

```
         select name, address from users group by
         name, address having count(*) > 1
```

But my problem is ... say I  have another field called credit. I would want to compare credits in the duplicate values and would take the second   if the second credit is higher than the first (that is max)

```
         select name, address,  from users group by
         name, address having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: **WHAT** database and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by **many** database systems - **SQL** is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often **vendor-specific** - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Comment: @marc_s I am playing with SQLite

Comment: @MichaelDurrant I am yet to figure something worthy of presenting here

Answer (score 0):

use

```
select A.name, A.address, max ( A.credits ) mc from users A
where (A.name, A.address) in
(
   select B.name, B.address from users B group by
   B.name, B.address having count(*) > 1
)
group by A.name, A.address
```